# ListView, image and SQL question

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, listview

I have the next code:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="moreI" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" onprerender="moreI_PreRender">


    <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="100px" Height="100px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
 // and so on till the </ItemTemplate> and </asp:ListView>
```

I have the next method:

```
    protected void checkTheImage() 
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in moreI.Items)
    {
        ((Image)item.FindControl("Image1")).ImageUrl = "noImage.jpg";
    }
}
```

And the sql

```
    protected Boolean ImageCheck()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\***.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    string CommandText2 = "SELECT noImage FROM Machreta WHERE noImage = 1";
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(CommandText2, connection);
    connection.Open();
    Boolean check = (Boolean)command2.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();

    //here i stoped without the return.
```

I have the table Machreta with the column `noImage (bit)`.

- where the `noImage = true`, i want to show the `noImage.jpg` from the `checkTheImage()`
- where the `noImage = false`, i want to show the `'<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>'`

I have problem with the logic, maybe too many hours of work... what can you suggest me?

Comment: I don't know what good is this for : SELECT noImage FROM Machreta WHERE noImage = 1, it will always be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think you need to update the datasource that bind to the listview to contain the boolean variable that specify if to use the ImageUrl or the noimage.jpeg

<asp:ListView ID="moreI" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" onprerender="moreI_PreRender">


    <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="100px" Height="100px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# checkImage(Eval("ImageUrl"), Eval("noImage")) %>' />
 // and so on till the </ItemTemplate> and </asp:ListView>

  protected string checkTheImage(object ImageUrl, object noImage) 
{
    if((bool)noImage)
    {
        return "noImage.jpg";
    }
else
{
return ImageUrl.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. the VWD give the error: Since checkTheImage returns void, a retrun keyword must not be followd by an object expression.

Comment: You are welcome, sorry for this mistake but i was wrting the code in the editor and i didn't checked it on visual studio as i use this technique alot ;)